# Regular Expression for Password - Exclude certain characters

Tags: regex, validation, passwords, blacklist

I have a requirement to develop a password validation with the following criteria:
 - at least one upper case letter;
 - at least one lower case letter;
 - at least on digit;
 - may include some special characters;
 - must have a length between 8 and 12;

I have developed this:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!#$&%*_+-=?|]).{8,12}
```

But recently, the requirements have changed and I need to implement a black list of characters, for example:
 - password must not have the letter "o" or "O"; // lower case and upper case O for Oscar
 - password must not have the digit 0; // number zero

How do I go about keeping the initial requirements and add these new validations?
Thanks

**JB**

Comment: Why do you care what letters the password has or doesn't have? ie. what is the point of the "no O's" rule?

Comment: I'd tell your teacher to come up with a real world scenario. Your 'question' read's as some question from some far forgotten test, that was given up long ago in the pursuit of reality :)

Answer (score 3):

Problem is hyphen appearing in the middle of character class. Hyphen can remain unescaped only when it is first or last in character class so following regex should work:

```
(?!.*[oO0])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!#$&%*+=?|-]).{8,12}
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/AI928rE8Aj

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback but I wasn't clear on your answer.
The regex expression I have is working fine for the initial requirements.

But i need to know how I can have for example:
- at least 1 lower case letter excluding the letter 'o'

I have:
(?=.*[a-z])

And if I change it to:
(?=.*[a-np-z]) it will only validate at least one lower case letter from 'a' to 'n' and 'p' to 'z'. I want the validation to fail in case of a 'o'

Comment: Hello and thank you once again for your feedback.
I tried this approach earlier but doesn't work because it only excludes a password that has exactly 'o', 'O' or / and '0'... or ends in one of these characters

Simple test I did:
@"(?!.*[abc])(?=.*[a-z]).{1,10}";

Test passwords:
"a" - failed
"b" - failed
"c" - failed
"qwerty" - passed 
"hello" - passed
"abc" - failed
"helloa" - failed
"heallo" - passed
"ahello" - passed

Comment: Not sure about that, see this demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/GWGNG5WiYz and case # 2 and 3 it rejects `aoC!Xyz1` but accepts `abC!Xyz1`